# javax.ws.rs Client Timeout

Tags: java, jax-rs

So I know there are 2 timeouts that can be set (namely the READ and CONNECT) timeouts but neither of those are able to satisfy what I need.

I want to simply abort the connection if it has been up for TIMEOUT milliseconds.

I experimented by making the call to an endpoint that simply sleeps for 5000ms. I set the READ_TIMEOUT to 2000ms which should work because the connection doesn't send bytes for the amount of time it is asleep but the timeout never occurs. This leads me to believe there is some heartbeat bytes being sent?

1. Is there a way to close this connection after X amount of time?
2. Thats all I really need lol

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe you should show us your code.  If you're talking about a simple socket connection, I can't think why you wouldn't time out waiting for a response.  I've used sockets quite a bit.  If there were an underlying heartbeat for a standard socket that affected the timeout, that would kinda make the timeout useless.

Comment: I would think you could do some multi-threaded thing to set a timer that goes off after your timeout period and kills the connection, but that's pretty yucky.  What I hope for you is that there's just something subtle you're missing that will let all this work when you find it.

Comment: Ooops...javax.ws.rs.  Just noticed that in the subject....

Comment: Looking at javax.ws.rs, I think my above comments still hold.  I do see that it is an abstraction that requires an underlying implementation.  So maybe that implementation does have a hearbeat or something.  Dunno.